# Flutter: Toggle a Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter

How can I toggle the visibility of a`bottomNavigationBar` based on condition?

In my app, I have the app widget where everything inside the app resides (including the navigation bar), and a `welcome` view which is only shown when launching the app for the first time.

**My goal** is to hide the navigation bar while inside the welcome view, and toggle it back on when exiting that view.

Here's my code: (it works briefly, but the navigationbar toggles itself off shortly after)

```html
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    body: isNewUser ? const WelcomeView() : const HomePage(),
     bottomNavigationBar: isNewUser
          ? null : BottomNavigationBar()
  }
  
  // then inside welcome view, there's a button that redirects users to HomePage:
  
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    goToHomePage(context);
    keyApp.currentState!.setState(() {
      keyApp.currentState!.isNewUser = false; // toggling
    });
  },
  child: const Text(
    'Skip Tutorial >',
    style: TextStyle(
      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You will need to provide more context so that I can help. I also recommend you use SizedBox.shrink() instead of null in the tertiary statement following  bottomNavigationBar: